# Can't understand these lines in apache log file

Tags: apache, logging

I get lines like these

```
101.102.2.137 - - [13/Sep/2013:15:20:53 +0300] "\xda\x85^iK\x94bUt\xb2DR\x12l\x19\x11\x06\xd0\x86\x88\xf43\x0c\x14e\x17\xab\xf8SUGF{L\xb0T\x91\x12\xeb\xce\xdc\x1e\x19NS\xc6+\x82;c\r\x96\xd7@\xfb\x01n" 400 226
46.47.127.146 - - [13/Sep/2013:15:23:00 +0300] "-" 408 -
92.163.103.246 - - [13/Sep/2013:15:27:23 +0300] "-" 408 -
124.84.210.50 - - [13/Sep/2013:15:59:56 +0300] "\x9e\x89\xd6" 200 4487
```

in my apache log and i don't know what do they mean. I use WAMP just to test stuff i don't know how can anyone get my IP to connect.
Can you tell me what the lines mean?

Comment: they might just be guessing. if your router opens the apache port(s) you define in your conf, the server will be accessible from the outside.

Comment: _Looks_ like attempts to exploit a buggy UTF-8 implementation... in other words, likely random port scanning.